# How to get XYZ coordinates from Kinect in C++

Tags: c++, opencv, augmented-reality, kinect-sdk

I'm new to kinect. I'm working on a project of Augmented Reality in Visual Studio using c++.
I'm looking for a way to get all the point coordinates(X,Y,Z) through kinect, but i'm having a hard time figuring it out. Can any one help me with it?
How do i get the points from the depth stream?

I'm Using Kinect V1 for xbox 360.

Comment: can you access the depth values and just dont know how to compute 3d points from it? or don't you know how to access the depth values?

Comment: I'm Completely new to this. I don't know how to access depth values.

Comment: try starting with http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/user_guide/ug_kinect.html

Comment: Thanks a lot. However the link to download openni library takes me to apple and says Page you are looking for is not found. I'll try to find other sources. but can you point me to one if you know any other then this? @Micka

Comment: I'm reading that openni is closed down by apple.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming Kinect v2: The simplest way of doing this is using the `ICoordinateMapper::MapDepthFrameToCameraSpace` (see docs [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.kinect.kinect.icoordinatemapper.aspx)).

```
IKinectSensor *sensor;
UINT16 *depthPoints;
...
// initialize the sensor and grab a depth frame and get depthPoints
...
const int nPixels = 512 * 424;
std::vector<CameraSpacePoint> cameraPoints;
cameraPoints.resize(nPixels);
ICoordinateMapper *cm = dev->get_CoordinateMapper();
if (cm != nullptr) {
  cm->MapDepthFrameToCameraSpace(nPixels, &depthPoints[0], nPixels, &cameraPoints[0]);
  cm->Release();
}
// use XYZs in cameraPoints
```

Note that this only works when you have a live connection to the device. If you have previously saved raw depth frames to disk and read them back e.g. on another computer, then look at using the `ICoordinateMapper` function `GetDepthCameraIntrinsics` or `GetDepthFrameToCameraSpaceTable` and save that data along with the frames to allow offline conversion to XYZ.

**Edit:**

For easily getting started:

- Kinect v1: try using [Kinect Common Bridge v1](https://github.com/MSOpenTech/KinectCommonBridge/tree/master) and the [CoordinateMapper::MapDepthFrameToSkeletonFrame](https://github.com/MSOpenTech/KinectCommonBridge/blob/master/KinectCommonBridge/CoordinateMapper.h) method.
- Kinect v2: try using [Kinect Common Bridge v2](https://github.com/MSOpenTech/KinectCommonBridge/tree/2.0) and the [KCBMapDepthFrameToCameraSpace](https://github.com/MSOpenTech/KinectCommonBridge/blob/2.0/KCBv2/KCBv2Lib.h) function.

Comment: If you are completely new to Kinect2 then you could try using [Kinect Common Bridge](https://github.com/MSOpenTech/KinectCommonBridge/tree/2.0) which makes device handling much easier. It has a similar method to that described here i.e. `KCBMapDepthFrameToCameraSpace`.

Comment: Sorry i forgot to mention i have Kinect v1 for xbox 360 :\

Comment: @Sagar OK, there is a [KCB for Kinect v1](https://github.com/MSOpenTech/KinectCommonBridge/tree/master) which has a CoordinateMapper method called MapDepthFrameToSkeletonFrame that should achieve the same thing